# How to find $R(4,3)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How to find the Ramsey numbers?I am new in graph theory and I need help.
By PHP,I have proved that $R(3,3)$=6.But I am finding difficulty when the numbers get bigger. Is their any particular method of finding it.

For example : Please show mw how to find $R(4,3)$ .

Comment: In general, finding Ramsey numbers is quite difficult.

Comment: There is a theorem that says R(4,3) =9 here: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/Ramsey43.shtml. This may give you an idea about the time complexity if you are not already aware of it to find large numbers: https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.1842 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210653/algorithms-for-calculating-r5-5-and-r6-6

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no known method of finding Ramsey numbers (**Edit:** No efficient known method; i.e brute-force bash and 'clever' brute force bashes are the best algorithms so far, and even these are too slow to compute e.g $R(5,5)$ or $R(6,6)$ afaik; see the wikipedia article for more). In general, the best you can do is bound them. For instance, $R(r,s)\leq R(r-1,s)+R(r,s-1)$ allows you to say that $R(4,3)\le R(3,3)+R(4,2)=10$ is one such bound.

To say that $R(r,s)=n$, one must provide a colouring of $K_{n-1}$ that works (which is often the easier part), and also prove that any colouring of $K_n$ must contain a clique. No known method is known for either of the two parts. For the specific case of $R(4,3)$,

[image]

is an example of why $R(4,3)>8$ -- this colouring (with the complementary edges coloured red) has no blue complete graphs on $4$ edges, nor any complete red graphs on $3$ edges.

To show why $R(4,3)\le 9$, note that if you have $9$ vertices, and a colouring, consider any vertex, $V$. If the red degree is $4$ or higher, these four either form a blue clique or a red triangle with $V$. Thus the red degree of any vertex is at most $3$ so the blue degree is at least $5$. But it is well known that any five vertices have a triangle and thus the theorem is proven.

Comment: Of course there is a known method for finding any particular Ramsey number, namely, exhaustive search. It's a finite problem, after all. It's just that there's no *efficient* method, once you get beyond the smallest examples.

Comment: I heard that $R(m,n)$=${m+n-2} \choose {m-1}$. Is it true?? If it is true , then do anyone have any proof?

Comment: @Sufaid, it's nonsense.

Comment: Yeah, @GerryMyerson, that's what I had in mind when i wrote it; only now that I look back on it do i see how it could be interpreted badly.

Comment: @auscrypt I think the part that claims "But it is well known that any five vertices have a triangle and thus the theorem is proven" is incorrect. Any 6 vertices have a triangle as per `R(3,3)`. But 5 vertices don't have to have a triangle. Therefore your proof is incomplete.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sufaid's comment is indeed wrong, and it would trivialize the computation of Ramsey numbers if it were true, but I don't think it's nonsense. Doesn't it become true if you just replace $=$ with $\leq$ ? That inequality seems to be what you get by just iterating the standard argument, "Consider any vertex  and see how many of its incident edges have one or the other color; apply an induction hypothesis to the other ends of the edges of one color; etc." without doing anything clever in addition?

Comment: @Andreas, yes, the inequality is true. It's attributed to Erdös and Szekeres at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Asymptotics